# OpenErp - External Id Bulk Update

Tags: python, postgresql, constraints, odoo

I need a way to add, some external ID's in the system without having to add them manually or by .csv

Is there any way to do this by a module, that maybe updates all the ir.model.data tables of the db?

If so, what module should i look for? Is there any in existence, so i can make a new one based on it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a module by loading the data through xml or csv. Have a look at any module with a security\ir.model.access.csv file.

So to load data, create new module and add a csv file with the name of the table you want to load into (eg ir.model.data.csv) and add it to the `__openerp__.py` file under 'update_xml'.